# Androidでナビゲーションバーを常に表示させたいです。

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, navigationbar

Androidで確認した時にナビゲーションバーを常に表示させたいです。

実機のAndroidのバージョンは7.0
Galaxy Experience version8.1を使用しています。

現状、下から上にスワイプすることでナビゲーションバーを表示しています。
これをスワイプせずにデフォルトでナビゲーションバーを表示させたいです。

### 試したこと

- MainActivity.javaの以下のコードを削除。
  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
  これを削除しましたが、デフォルトでナビゲーションバーが表示されません(スワイプしないと表示されません)。

**削除前のコード**

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        getWindow().getDecorView()
                .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
```

以上です。
ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご回答いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/281064

Comment: マルチポスト先で解決済み